# "The one three blocks" meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "the one three blocks" in the below sentences?

> Good but not as good as **the one three blocks** away.

> Just in case **the one three blocks** down isn't close enough.

Comment: You are not parsing it correctly--it is "the one" + "three blocks away"...See Clares answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The one three blocks away

contains a reduced relative clause. You can understand it as

> The one [which/that is]  three blocks away.

*One* is a pronoun here. *The one* refers to a referent that was probably mentioned before or is otherwise identifiable by the listener. *Three* is part of a measurement in units of   blocks, that is *how many blocks*.

An example with more context:

> This Indian restaurant is  good. But it's not as good as the one [that  is] three blocks away. Let's go to that one instead.

As for *blocks*: Streets are divided into blocks. A block usually refers to the length of street between two intersections. So, *a block* can be used as is a unit of distance.

See [Oxford](https://web.archive.org/web/20190427205221/https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/block):

> 2.4 *North American* The length of one side of a block, especially as a measure of distance

Something (such as a post-office, bookstore, restaurant) "three blocks away" or "three blocks down (the street)" is something that you have to travel three blocks to get to. You will cross two intersections and be "three blocks away"  or "three blocks down"  from the position or location you started from.

Blocks do not have a uniform distance measured in such units as  feet,  miles or kilometers. The distance of *one block* measured in standard units varies from one city to another and even from one part of a city to another.  [Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108211018/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68498.html) reports that there are 8 to 20 city blocks to a mile (1.6 kilometers).

Comment: Thank you. But what about "the one three" means? Is it 1/3 or ...

Comment: Dont consider "the one three" as whole. They are two different parts of  one sentence. "The one" refers to a thing in particular, its not referred as number here. The word "Three" in your sentences defines number/position of things.

Comment: ohh, what a idiot i am!

Comment: @Ali I've edited my answer. I think you are confused by *one* and *three* being next to each other. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Ali Easy mistake to make! Do not be so hard on yourself. "With time comes wisdom".

Comment: Hello, Clare. There are many previous questions and answers addressing whiz-deletion / reduced relative clauses.